# E[X|X +Y] = E[Y|X +Y]

Tags: conditional-expectation

I am asked to prove that for two integrable independent and identical distributed random variables E[X|X +Y] = E[Y|X +Y] and then compute it .

What I have done and the way I am thinking about it is to let X+Y=Z so we can have something of the form  E(Z-Y/Z) so we can use the 'distributive' property but nothing really happens from there except from finding that for the second part the outcome is E(X+Y)/2

Can anyone give me a hint for the first part?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Because $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d., $E[X|X+Y]=E[Y|X+Y]$ follows from symmetry. Your second part isn't quite correct either: from the first part:
\begin{align*}
E[X|X+Y]=E[Y|X+Y]&=\frac{1}{2}\left(E[X|X+Y]+E[Y|X+Y]\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}E[X+Y|X+Y]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(X+Y).
\end{align*}